# Development environment for cockpit-dashboard

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, cockpit

I am trying to customize [cockpit](https://github.com/cockpit-project). I need cockpit to monitor a kubernetes cluster running on ubuntu 16.04 servers. I prefer to run the cockpit as a pod. My development server is also running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

While exploring development environment I found a [page](https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/tree/master/containers) where it is mentioned to mount the source path to the container path `~/.local/share/cockpit`. I am able to mount it but the page is loading from a different path in the container i.e. `/usr/share/cockpit/kubernetes`. The files seems to be in gzip (eg: `index.html.gz`).

I am new to node.js or any similar environment. How am I supposed to keep my changes up to date from `~/.local/share/cockpit` to `/usr/share/cockpit/kubernetes` in gzip format? I have seen references to webpack. Not sure if I need to use that. Even if I have to use that, should I run webpack inside the container to package contents in `~/.local/share/cockpit` to `/usr/share/cockpit/kubernetes`? Or it should be packaged using webpack in my Ubuntu machine and create a container based on that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot find any detailed docs regarding cockpit development environment anywhere.